# What is the proper type-hinting for this function which accepts either an instance or a builder, and returns the instance?

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting, python-typing

Here is a simple function that receives either an instance of `Foo`, in which case it returns the instance, or an instance of a class which can build `Foo`, in which case it builds and return a new instance of `Foo`.

The logic is simple and the code runs without error, but both pylance and mypy complain that my return types don't match the type hinting in the signature.

```py
# python 3.9.5
from typing import TypeVar, Union


class Foo:
    pass


class FooBuilder:
    def build(self) -> Foo:
        return Foo()


_F = TypeVar("_F", bound=Foo)
_FB = TypeVar("_FB", bound=FooBuilder)


def get_foo(x: Union[_F, _FB]) -> _F:
    if isinstance(x, Foo):
        return x  # <<< mypy error #1
    elif isinstance(x, FooBuilder):
        return x.build()  # <<< mypy error #2; pylance error


assert isinstance(get_foo(Foo()), Foo)  # passes without error
assert isinstance(get_foo(FooBuilder()), Foo)  # passes without error
```

Pylance only complains about the second return:

`Expression of type "Foo*" cannot be assigned to return type "_F@get_foo"`

Whereas mypy complains about both:

`main.py:19: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Foo", expected "_F")  [return-value]`

`main.py:21: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Foo", expected "_F")  [return-value]`

Neither error was helpful when searching, other than to determine it doesn't think the return types match the signature, but to me, it looks like they do.

In real life, I'm passing instances that inherit from `Foo` and `FooBuilder`, thus the use of `TypeVar`, instead of simply using the classes directly in the signature of the function. It seems wrong that one of my types (`_FB`) is only present once in the signature instead of twice, which is usually why I'd use `TypeVar`; however, it's important the function take two different types, each with different base classes, yet only return the non-builder instance. Is there something other than `TypeVar` I should be using for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem does not only lie in the `get_foo` function annotation, but in your type guards within its body.

Let's focus on the first case only for now. You specified that you can pass an instance of `_F` to `get_foo` and it will return an instance **of that same type** `_F`. That is what the type variable in a function signature is for: Binding to the type(s) of the passed argument(s) and collapsing the return type accordingly.

Say you had the `FooSub` class inheriting from `Foo` and you passed an instance of `FooSub` to `get_foo`. The type variable `_F` would collapse to `FooSub` and the return type would be expected to be `FooSub`.

But your `isinstance(x, Foo)` check in the function body acts as a **type guard**. Past that check, <del>the type checker</del> *Mypy* assumes **`x` is of type `Foo`** and no longer of whatever `_F` was. <del>As we established you could have passed a `FooSub` object, which would require you to return a `FooSub` object. Since `FooSub` is a **subtype** of and thus more **narrow** than `Foo`,  returning an instance of `Foo` is not type safe.</del>

---

**<EDIT>** The specific way in which a type checker should *interpret* this type guard is a matter of debate/implementation. Arguably the most sane approach is to still consider `x` to be of type `_F` because the upper bound defined for `_F` is `Foo`. Pyright seems to already treat it as such. But for Mypy this is still [an unresolved issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/10817). Thanks to @SUTerliakov for pointing this out in a comment.

In other words, your use of the `isinstance` check is not wrong per se. It is just not clear enough for some type checkers in the presence of a type variable. **</EDIT>**

---

If you know what you are doing and that `isinstance` approach is really necessary, you could simply `cast` the variable `x` to the type `_F` before returning or use a `type: ignore` directive. But I would *not recommend* that because I doubt that `isinstance` check is necessary at all. This brings me to the second case.

`FooBuilder` as you showed it above is **not generic**. Its `build` return type is fixed to `Foo`. Therefore whatever subtype of `FooBuilder` is passed to `get_foo`, the output of its `build` method call will **always** be inferred as an instance of `Foo` and nothing else, specifically not `_F`.

So assuming subclasses of `FooBuilder` can actually return **different** types (subclasses of `Foo`), you should *probably* make `FooBuilder` [generic](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#user-defined-generic-types) anyway. Although my suggested solution below works fine even if `FooBuilder` is *not* generic.

Then, if all you care about in the second use case is that the object passed to `get_foo` has a `build` method and is generic in terms of that method's return type, you could define a [generic **protocol**](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#generic-protocols) for that. This part is actually important.

Lastly, if you make that protocol [`runtime_checkable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.runtime_checkable), you can start with an `isinstance` check for that protocol, do what you need to do with that builder object and eventually return its `build` output. Since that covers one of the two possible types of the union the argument `x` is an instance of, the type checker will know that the *remaining* branch (equivalent to the previous `isinstance` check returning `False`) covers the other type, namely `_F`. So you do not need to explicitly check that again. Instead you can simply assume that `x` will be of type `_F`.

Altogether, I would recommend something like this:

```py
from typing import Generic, Protocol, TypeVar, Union, runtime_checkable


class Foo:
    ...


_F = TypeVar("_F", bound=Foo, covariant=True)


class FooBuilder(Generic[_F]):
    """Example of the actual builder base class"""
    def __init__(self, foo_cls: type[_F]) -> None:
        self.foo_cls = foo_cls

    def build(self) -> _F:
        return self.foo_cls()


@runtime_checkable
class BuildsFoo(Protocol[_F]):
    def build(self) -> _F: ...


def get_foo(x: Union[_F, BuildsFoo[_F]]) -> _F:
    if isinstance(x, BuildsFoo):
        return x.build()
    return x
```

(That is a literal ellipsis `...` in the `BuildsFoo.build` method.)

Usage demo:

```py
...

class Bar(Foo):
    ...


obj1 = get_foo(Bar())
obj2 = get_foo(FooBuilder(Bar))
reveal_type(obj1)  # note: Revealed type is "Bar"
reveal_type(obj2)  # note: Revealed type is "Bar"
```

Here is a [Mypy Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.9&flags=strict&gist=0586c302e2d40914eec02eb1802ef4fa) with this code.

Comment: Nice answer! I love how you explain the reasoning behind confirmed `mypy` bug which is known for a few years:) https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/10817 OP `mypy` error #1 (in first conditional branch) should not be there, it's a bug, and narrowing does not magically transform `x` to another object. The fact that narrowing works this way in `mypy` (no matter is it upcasting or downcasting, your final type is always exactly type of 2nd `isinstance` argument) does not mean that you exchange a typevar to its upper bound. Assignments of anything not of type `_F` to x could be forbidden instead

Comment: (Upvoted, my previous comment is not fully sarcastic - you really explain why things do not work with `mypy` now, please just mention that this is not intended)

Comment: @SUTerliakov Thank you for pointing this out. I included those insights into the answer. I don't fully agree that this is unambiguously _a bug_ in the sense that it is just _theoretically_ wrong. I think there is some room for debate as to how exactly such a type guard should affect the inference of `x`. In other words, it depends on what _we want_ the type checker to think. But I agree that the approach already taken by Pyright of still viewing it as `_F` probably makes the most sense in practice. And I hope Mypy will follow soon.